# Function not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I have the JS below. I'm trying to run the `slideout.close();` event with smoothstate `onStart`. My code is below and i'm currently getting an error in the console. Could someone please help me out.

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    slideout();
});

function slideout() {
    var slideout = new Slideout({
      'panel': document.getElementById('slideout-content'),
      'menu': document.getElementById('slideout-nav'),
      'padding': 256,
      'tolerance': 70,
      'side': 'right'
    });

    $('.mobile-nav__icon').on('click', function() {
        slideout.toggle();
    });
}

$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var options = {
    prefetch: true,
    cacheLength: 2,
    onStart: {
      duration: 860,
      render: function ($container) {
        $container.addClass('is-exiting');
        smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
        slideout.close();
      }
    },
    onReady: {
      duration: 0,
      render: function ($container, $newContent) {
        $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
        $container.html($newContent);
      }
    },
    onAfter: function() {
        slideout();
    }
  },
  smoothState = $('#animate-wrapper').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Comment: I'd be great if you specified what the errors actually were

Comment: `script.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: slideout.close is not a function`

Comment: `slideout` is function, not an object. Maybe you're trying to access the local one?

Comment: How would you suggest I set up my code so I can run slideout.close(); on smoothstate onstart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a global function called `slideout`, within which you have a local variable called `slideout` that is the one that refers to a `Slideout` object - you can't access that local variable from other functions. When you try to use `slideout.close()` that is looking for a `.close()` method on the *function*.

One fix would be to change the name of the variable or function and make the variable global too, so that you can access it anywhere. But adding more globals is messy.

I think it should be fine to combine all of your code into a single document ready handler, so that everything is in the same scope without needing any globals (you would still need to use a different name for the variable).

I can't test the following because I don't have whatever `Slideout` is, but:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';

  var slideout;  // variable that is local to the doc ready handler function
                 // and accessible to all code within that handler

  function initSlideout() {    // function renamed
    slideout = new Slideout({  // assign to variable declared above
      'panel': document.getElementById('slideout-content'),
      'menu': document.getElementById('slideout-nav'),
      'padding': 256,
      'tolerance': 70,
      'side': 'right'
    });
  }
  initSlideout();

  $('.mobile-nav__icon').on('click', function() {
    slideout.toggle();
  });

  var options = {
    prefetch: true,
    cacheLength: 2,
    onStart: {
      duration: 860,
      render: function ($container) {
        $container.addClass('is-exiting');
        smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
        slideout.close();
      }
    },
    onReady: {
      duration: 0,
      render: function ($container, $newContent) {
        $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
        $container.html($newContent);
      }
    },
    onAfter: function() {
      initSlideout();
    }
  },
  smoothState = $('#animate-wrapper').smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Comment: everything seems to work now, however I just need the slideout to reinitialize after smoothstate is complete. This was working before but now this bit doesn't work. `onAfter: function() {
        slideout();
    }`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that. (In my answer I said you didn't seem to call `slideout()` anywhere else, but actually you do.) Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated.